# Firebase - How can I save each object item by a child slug, opposed to their index number?

Tags: javascript, firebase

How can I save items in an object as there nested tag (as apposed to there index number).

For instance Im working with the follow data:

```
 {
  "all_items": [
    {
      "id": 900,
      "item_id": 20,
      "name": "First Item",
      "slug": "first-item"
    },
    {
      "id": 800,
      "item_id": 21,
      "name": "Second Item",
      "slug": "second-item"
    }
  ]
}
```

saving it like so:

```
var dataRef = new Firebase("https://<firebase-Id>.firebaseio.com/");
var data=  {"all_items": [....]};      // This is the truncated object above.
dataRef.update(data); //saving
```

In firebase it saves each value by their index as seen here:

> [image]

How can I have the first item the **0** to be saved as its items slug **first-item**
and the second item (index number **1**) to save as **second-item**, and so on.

So far I've worked with snapshots like so:

```
dataRef.child('all_items')once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

    //KEY
    var key = childSnapshot.key();
    console.log('key: ', key); // returns 0 then 1

     //VALUE
     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
     console.log('childData: ', childData); //returns first item then second
     console.log('slug: ', childData.slug);//returns 'first-item' then 'second-item'

      //issue is here. I would like to use
     key.update(childData.slug)
     //but firebase returns "TypeError: key.update is not a function

  });
```

Now that I can log them, how can I save them where I overwrite the index number by its slug?

Answer (score 0):

I did so by creating a new instance of the firebase reference inside a loop assigning the path for each to is slug:

```
     for (var i in data.all_items) {

          singleObj = data.all_items[i];
         console.log('one item:',singleObj);

        var newDataRef = new Firebase("https://<firebase-id>.firebaseio.com/all_items/"+ val.slug+'/');
        newDataRef.update(singleObj)

       }
```